# What comes first: pendingTransactions, logs, newBlockHeaders?

Tags: blockchain, pending-transactions, logs

I am trying to understand the order in which the data propagates.

My understanding at the moment is:

Assuming someone just made `sendTransaction` call, then...

1. First we would receive `pendingTransactions` describing the pending transaction. This would be issued as soon as someone makes the a mutation. At this point, this transaction has not been included in any [blocks](/questions/tagged/blocks), and it is possible that it will be dropped.
2. Next, we would receive `logs` associated with the transaction. At this point, the latter transaction is already included in a block, i.e. some node has processed the transaction.
3. Finally, we would receive `newBlockHeaders`. This would fire once a block including the transaction and the associated logs has been mined.

Is my understanding correct?

The main thing that I am trying to figure out is if I can trust logs.

If I subscribe to [`Sync`](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/3b214306770e86bc3a64e67c2b5bdb566b4e94a7/contracts/PancakePair.sol#L59), is it safe to trust the values provided in the payload or should I add some delay after which I `eth_call` [`getReserves`](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core/blob/3b214306770e86bc3a64e67c2b5bdb566b4e94a7/contracts/PancakePair.sol#L38-L42)?

Comment: I don't know the exact order but events do not exist if the transaction is pending, so they should appear only when the block is mined, if after newBlockHeaders.